# Auto Iframe size not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

I had a site running on [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) which was working perfectly before IE9. It still works perfectly but only in compatibility mode.

The problem is in the Javascript function which I used earlier to call an Iframe (this basically has 4 input forms which are loaded one after the other, different sizes) but now its showing an error. I've tried searching forums and on Google but couldn't find a solution. The error is in this line:

```
h = document.frames('blockrandom').document.body.scrollHeight;
```

generated by IE9 (error code 5002, at character 3rd). Are there any alternatives?

```
function iFrameHeight()  {
   var h = 0;
   if ( !document.all ) {
       h = document.getElementById('blockrandom').contentDocument.height;
       document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = h + 60 + 'px';
   } 
   else if ( document.all ) {
      h = document.frames('blockrandom').document.body.scrollHeight;
      document.all.blockrandom.style.height = h + 20 + 'px';
   }
```

}

Comment: `document.all` so 1999 browser detection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to achieve this without relying on `document.frames` or `document.all`. Have a look at this [short tutorial by Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/iframe-height-scrollbar-example/). After reading that, you should end up with something like the following:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('blockrandom');
iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
```